# Inserting or part replacement with regular expressions

Tags: regex

A very simple one for someone that knows the answer.  I'm working in EditPat Lite, and have a list in the format:

```
"Origin - Destination 1234.5 miles"
```

I need to insert a ',' between the destinations and distances, and can identify the place to insert using `( [0-9]+.[0-9]+ miles)`.  But I know not how to insert the comma.  Have searched for solutions using various brackets, but nothing works.  I need to prevent the strings being replaced by the regular expression.

Grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a regexp replacement function, which I suppose you have. In it, you can refer to matched expressions (as the other answer says, this is normally done with `$0` or `\0`, or different numbers for sub-matches.

You can either replace the regexp you have with `,\0` , which means "a comma, followed by the thing that is being replaced", or you can use a non-consuming match, so you replace the 0-character string just before the regexp with a comma: `(?= [0-9]+.[0-9]+ miles)` matches this "empty" string.

This type of match is called "positive lookahead". It's also available in negative and lookbehind flavours: `(?!...)`, `(?<=...)`, `(?<!...)`.

Answer (score 0):

These are just guesses, but try replacing with:

- `,$1`
- `,\1`

Comment: @geotheory: He means use regex based replacing and the identifiers `$1` or `\1` inside the text to replace. Inside that text you can specify arbitrary text, not just the referers. So you can also add a `,` there.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not sure what you're saying. Searching the file for `( [0-9]+.[0-9]+ miles)` and replacing with `,$1` or `\1` (whichever one works) will add a comma before all distances.

Comment: sure, you are right. My comment was an explanation for the OP because your question lacks any form of that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. In EditPad it seems 0 not 1 is the replacement identifier.

Comment: Normally (I don't know of exceptions), \0 is "the entire expression", while \1 is the first subexpression. You wrote your entire expression in parentheses, so the entire thing is a subexpression, and it would be equal to \0. If you didn't actually use the parentheses in your code, \1 wouldn't work, because then there is no "first subexpression".